# How to capture IOException in onResponse method in OKHTTP3?

Tags: android, okhttp

I am using OkHttp3 for calling the services I need to call. The onResponse method looks like that:

```
@Override public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);}
```

I am developing a library, so the user should not be able to access that code. How could I propagate that Exception to the UI, so the developer that uses my library could deal with that IOException?

Comment: Are you exposing just an API or also an UI (Activity or View) and if it is just API - do you plan to be Asynchronous or Synchronous?

Comment: Only an API, and Asynchronous. But I solved it by declaring an interface, setting a new Instance of that Interface where I want the Exception to be captured, setting it where the Exception is launched, and calling a method inside that Interface that takes an Exception as argument.

Answer (score 2):

Make a custom method that get a custom listener as argument.

```
@Override private void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);}

public yourCustomMethod(MyListener listener) {
            try {
                //make the http call here
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                lister.IOException();
            }
}
```